# Finding the average of numbers from a two by two grid

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, methods, average

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CastleDefense {

// This is a global variable because both the public CastleDefense and main are using it 
double [][] grid;
public CastleDefense(int numRows, int numCols, Double[] scan) {
    int k = 0;
    grid = new double[numRows][numCols];
//loop that goes across the grid
  for (int r = 0; r<numRows; r++){
      if (numRows%2==0){
//stores the position of the grid, where we are. (k) ex. second row, we are on the first row and place          
          for (int g = 0; g<numCols; g++){
              grid [r][g] = scan[k];
          k++;
          }   
      }
      else{
          for (int j = numCols; j>=0;j--){
          grid [r][j] = scan[k];
          k++;              
      }
    }        
  }

}

public void findWeakest(){

}

public double getAverage(int startRow, int startCols, int endRow, int endCol){
    double average = 0.0;

    return average;        
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.in"));
//Making the array list to hold the doules in it
    ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>();
//Switching my aray list to a regular array to pass it to the constructor
    Double[] scan = new Double[arr.size()];
//loop to enter the doubles in the list
    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        arr.add(input.nextDouble());
        //System.out.println(arr.get(arr.size() - 1));
    }
//loop to calculate the number of rows and columns
    int i = (int) Math.sqrt(scan.length);
    while (i>0){
    if (scan.length % i == 0){
        rows = i;
        cols = scan.length/i;           
    }
    else
    i--;
}
//passing the values to the constructor
    CastleDefense pyramid = new CastleDefense (rows,cols, scan); 
}
}
```

This is the code I have so far. And my goal is to make a program reads from list of numbers (in data.in) store it in an array, then make a grid (closest to the best squared, so 3x4 not 1x12) inserting those numbers from the array to the grid reading left to right on the first row then right to left on the second row, so on and so fourth. Then taking from the grid, the first 2x2 and adding all of the numbers finding the average, and outputting the weakest 2x2 and average. I am currently stuck on getting the average of the numbers from the grid, and finding the weakest one.

Comment: If you have any questions or anything please ask away

Comment: What exactly are you getting stuck on?

Comment: I don't know what the next step is. How should I go on building my getAverage method? What to pass on to the parameters? and How to take every 2x2 possible of the grid?

Comment: I am not sure of your requirements but the method I do is, get a piece of paper and work through an example. Then translate the process into code.